# Creating newcommand for a tens frame grid using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, ifthenelse

I'm trying to create tens frames to model addition of numbers. I'd love it if `\tensframe{#1}{#2}` would show #1 green circles starting on the left and growing up, then #2 blue circles continuing from the green and then going up. If #1 or #1+#2 is greater than 5 it needs to carry over to the second column. Does someone know how to get this working?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\newcommand{\tensframe}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]%

\foreach \x in {1,2}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,5}
        \node[box] at (\x,\y){};
}

\foreach \x in {1,1}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#1}
      \filldraw[green] (\x,\y) circle (8pt);
}

\foreach \x in {1,1}{
   \foreach \y in {#1+1,...,5}
      \filldraw[blue] (\x,\y) circle (8pt);
}


    \foreach \y in {1,...,#2+#1-5}
      \filldraw[blue] (2,\y) circle (8pt);


\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\tensframe{1}{5}
\vspace{1cm}

\tensframe{3}{5}

\vspace{1cm}

\tensframe{2}{1}
    \end{document}
```

`\tensframe{1}{5}` is perfect
[image]

`\tensframe{3}{5}` is missing two blue circle in cell (2,2) and (2,3)
[image]

`\tensframe{2}{1}` isn't even defined (I think because I haven't got a range of values for the foreach ys), though if it was working would have green cells in (1,1) and (1,2) and a blue cell in (1,3) and look like this:
[image]

Does anyone know how this could be coded? Thanks so much

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one loop. First the node is created and name, and this name is used to fill it with the corresponding color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tensframe}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]%

\foreach \y in {1,...,5}{
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \ni using int(5*(\x-1)+\y)] in {1,2}{
            \node[box] (\ni) at (\x,\y){};
            \ifnum\ni<\numexpr#1+1\relax
                     \filldraw[green] (\ni.center) circle (8pt);
            \else
                \ifnum\ni<\numexpr#1+#2+1\relax
                     \filldraw[blue] (\ni.center) circle (8pt);
                \fi
            \fi
            
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\tensframe{1}{5}\ \tensframe{3}{5}\ \tensframe{2}{1}\ \tensframe{6}{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: New code to solve comment questions**

Following code shows a proposal to solve updated question through comments: an horizontal scheme and positioning them.

In this case, the `foreach` loop has been changed for two different commands, one will draw the grid (`tensh`, `tensv`) and another one will fill it (`filltens`). All this commands should be inside a `tikzpicture` which is not part of them.

`tens{v|h}` command has a mandatory parameter which is the name of the `matrix` node. As the grid is now a `node`, it can be referenced for positioning other nodes or be filled. The optional parameter will be used for positioning.

`filltens` command has three mandatory parameters, the first one is the name of the matrix to be filles with circles, while second and third are the number of green and blue circles inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\newcommand{\tensh}[2][]{%
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, inner sep, nodes in empty cells, 
        nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=.3333em},
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
        ampersand replacement=\&, #1] (#2) {
    |(#2-1)| \& |(#2-2)| \& |(#2-3)| \& |(#2-4)| \& |(#2-5)|\\
    |(#2-6)| \& |(#2-7)| \& |(#2-8)| \& |(#2-9)| \& |(#2-10)|\\};
}

\newcommand{\tensv}[2][]{%
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, inner sep, nodes in empty cells, 
        nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=.3333em},
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
        ampersand replacement=\&, #1] (#2){
    |(#2-5)| \& |(#2-10)| \\ |(#2-4)| \& |(#2-9)| \\ 
    |(#2-3)| \& |(#2-8)|  \\ |(#2-2)| \& |(#2-7)| \\ 
    |(#2-1)| \& |(#2-6)|\\};
}

\newcommand{\filltens}[3]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#2}
        \filldraw[green] (#1-\i.center) circle (8pt);
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(#2+\i)] in {1,...,#3}
        \filldraw[blue] (#1-\ni.center) circle (8pt);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tensh{a}
\tensv[above = 5mm of a.north east, anchor=south east]{b}
\tensh[right = 5mm of b.south east, anchor=south west] {c}
\tensv[right = 5mm of a.north east, anchor=north west]{d}
\filltens{a}{2}{4}
\filltens{b}{5}{3}
\filltens{c}{7}{2}
\filltens{d}{6}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is such neat code!! Thank you @Ignasi I am keen to make some horizontal tens frames too. I adjusted your code and got quite close with "\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \ni using int(5*(\y-1)+\x)] in {1,2}{
            \node[box] (\ni) at (\x,\y){};" though I'd love the top row to be filled before the bottom one. If you have the time, can you explain how this can be done? Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, is there a way to make horizontal and vertical codes work for sums greater than 10, where the tens frames are presented side by side. Eg \tensframex{9}{5} would present as \tensframe{9}{1} \tensframe{0}{4}. Thanks again!

Comment: @WendyTaylor Look at updated code. I hope it helps.

Comment: The horizontal frame is fantastic. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: bug fix

With expl3, I don't know if this interests you

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661181/creating-newcommand-for-a-tens-frame-grid-using-tikz
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tensframe}{ m m }
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [%
  box/.style={rectangle,draw=black, minimum~size=10mm},
  ]%
  \foreach \x in {1,2}
    {
      \foreach \y in {1,...,5}
      \node[box] at (\x,\y){};
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
      \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} < {6}
        {
          \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 1 }
          \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { ##1 }
        }
        {
          \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 2 }
          \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \int_eval:n { ##1 - 5 } }
        }
      \filldraw[green] (\l_tmpa_int,\l_tmpb_int) circle (8pt);
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
    {
      \int_compare:nNnTF {#1+##1} < {6}
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 1 }
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \int_eval:n { #1+##1 } }
      }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 2 }
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \int_eval:n { #1+##1 - 5 } }
      }
      \filldraw[blue] (\l_tmpa_int,\l_tmpb_int) circle (8pt);    
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tensframe{1}{5}
\vspace{1cm}

\tensframe{3}{5}

\vspace{1cm}

\tensframe{2}{1}

\vspace{1cm}

\tensframe{6}{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]